# MongoDB - How to query for strings which doesn't have any spaces (omit the strings with spaces) with length

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have queried the document with length match as:

sample format of document:

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e158e2de6facf7181cc368f"
    },
    "word": "as luck would have it",
}
```

query as:

```
{$where: "this.word.length == 20 "}
```

This matches the below :

```
{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e158e30e6facf7181cc3bdb"
    },
    "word": "adrenocorticotrophic",
}

{
    "_id": {
        "$oid": "5e158e2ee6facf7181cc38cf"
    },
    "word": "attributive genitive",
}
```

But I want to match only `adrenocorticotrophic` not the word with spaces like `attributive genitive`

May I know how could I match as above ?

Any help is appreciated !!

Comment: what is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: It is 4.2 mate.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Update :**

I've found another way(could be easy one) to do this, It should work with version >=`3.4`, try this :

```
/** When you split a string on a delimiter(space in your requirement) it would split string into an array of elements, 
* if no space in string then it would be only one element in array, then get a size & get docs having size less than 2 */

db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $lt: [
          {
            $size: {
              $split: [
                "$word", // word should not be null or '' (can be empty ' ')
                " "
              ]
            }
          },
          2
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/15k-aFvOjbh)

**Old :**

On MongoDB version >=`4.2`, You can do that using [$regexMatch](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/) :

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  /** A new field gets added to be true if word has spaces else be false */
  {
    $addFields: {
      wordHasSpaces: {
        $regexMatch: {
          input: "$word",
          regex: /\w+\s\w+/ /** This regex exp works if your string has plain characters A-Z */
        }
      }
    }
  },
  /** Remove docs where word has spaces */
  { $match: { wordHasSpaces: false } },
  /** Remove newly added unnecessary field */
  { $project: { wordHasSpaces: 0 } }
]);
```

Also to your existing code, you can stop using `$where` which is generally used to execute .js code in query & which is less performant, So on MongoDB v >=`3.4` You can use [$strLenCP](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/strLenCP/index.html) :

```
db.collection.aggregate([{$match : {$expr: {$eq : [{ $strLenCP:'$word'}, 20]}}}]) /** $expr is kind of replacement to $where */
```

**Test :** [MongoDB-Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Hmt-IHBXA7f)

Comment: Wow @whoami I just loved the way you explained it , Thanks a ton mate.....+1 , would be glad if some useful links to learn mongo (other than docs :))

Comment: @Codenewbie : Sign up here :: https://university.mongodb.com , it has free courses (directly from MongoDB)

Comment: Hey @whoami , could you please help me in Q  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60810426/how-to-match-a-string-consisting-special-character-like-hyphen-and-spaces