# How to match a string consisting special character like hyphen and spaces

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, pymongo

I have a string as:

```
word : 'A-Scan Ultrasonic'
```

How to match this with :

```
   'A Scan Ultrasonic'
```

I have tried my luck as

```
{word:{$regex:".*A Scan Ultrasonic.*",$options: 'i'}}
```

But this doesn't fetch any result

May I know how this can be matched , any help is appreciated , TIA

Comment: Let's say if one of your doc has :: `word : 'A-Scan Ultrasonic'` & another has `word : 'A-Ultrasonic'` & another has `word : 'A-Scan'` do you've to match all three ? Also what is your MongoDB version ?

Comment: Hey @whoami Its 4.2 mate , and No it should match only 'A-Scan Ultrasonic' not others as you mentioned....

Comment: Ok then it's not that easy & mongo doesn't provide anything straight forward unless you use regex to control it as stated in the given answer..

Comment: answer provides regex as `{"name": {$regex: "(-|\s)"}}` , but how to have the same as `'$match': { 'word': re.compile(r".*" + word + ".*") }`  ? .....here it checks if the word is contained in document word's , similarly the above , how to do this mate?

Comment: Hey @whoami , i somehow found a solution for this as replacing all spaces with a dot `'.'` and search for the word ......

Comment: not sure as I’ve not worked on pymongo anyway al d bst..

Answer (score 1):

It's actually no mongo thing, you should use proper regex.
Try with this:

```
{ name: { $regex: /.*A(-|\s)Scan(-|\s)Ultrasonic.*/}}
```

Comment: This is well explained mate , but what if I don't know where the hyphen's or spaces are but just match that string containing hyphen's and spaces?

Comment: `{"name": {$regex: "(-|\s)"}}`

Comment: Thanks mate , one more doubt how can I write a query for this like as:                         `'$match': { 'word': re.compile(r".*" + word + ".*") }` , here `word` is a variable and has some string value ....how can i do the same for your answer?

Comment: You're trying to write mongo regex by python, it's wrong. Write like this:
`regex_pattern = ".*" + word + ".*"
db.collectionname.find({'name':{'$regex':regex_patern}})`

Comment: yes , I am doing it with python mate.....but what would be the same way for the above regex?

Comment: I wrote, keep your python regex string to some variable, and pass like above

Comment: Does the aggregate follow same ? as I was doing it as an aggregate and it works fine ....

Comment: as you explained here regex_pattern = ".*" + word + ".*" ......where should the word be placed in {"name": {$regex: "(-|\s)"}}  ....hope you got my Q

Comment: Nowhere, because you want any string with space or hyphen. This is for aggregation:
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/regexMatch/

Comment: I have a functionality words containing some string , so it works right ?